# Can't find a bell curve drawing template

Tags: probability, statistics, graphing-functions

I am a math tutor inclusive of probability and statistics. For years, I have illustrated probability distribution concepts to my students using free-hand drawn (not very well) Normal and other distribution (e.g., Poisson, Chi-Squared) curves. Also for years, I have been in search of a tracing template made of plastic or some other solid material (not paper) to draw these curves, and have come up empty. Does anyone know where I might find one? Or, is there some reason these templates don't appear to exist in a solid form? I have seemingly located tracing templates for every other curve or two-dimensional object in existence. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to a 3D printer? You could make a stencil.

Comment: A great idea. But I don't know any CAD application, and that seems to be overkill since I am only trying to create a 3D version of a 2D object with a fixed height. Any suggestions on getting around the need for a .stl file?

Comment: You could print a curve onto paper, paste it onto card stock, and cut away everything on one side of the curve. Now you have a template.

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but I don't believe even the thickest cardstock (450 GSM?) will be durable enough for my needs.

I'm surprised these are nowhere to be found. It could be said that a market doesn't exist, but I have found templates for some truly strange curves. This alone encouraged me that I might find one someday. Does anyone know if there is an inherent reason for the omission?
Thank you for the reply!